# Spring no output-channel or replyChannel header available even though there are consumers

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using the following setup for a Spring Channel and its consumers:

```
<publish-subscribe-channel id="ImportReportChannel" datatype="com.something.ImportReport"/>

<transformer input-channel="ImportReportChannel" ref="ImportItemReportedTransformerBean"/>

<transformer  input-channel="ImportReportChannel" 
              output-channel="ImportReportHtmlChannel" 
              ref="ImportReportToHtmlTransformer"/>
```

For some reason I get the following Error from ImportReportChannel:

> DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel
>   header available

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 subscribers; one has an output channel, the other one doesn't. A transformer in this context, without and `output-channel`, makes no sense. You're executing a transformation but not sending it anywhere.

Comment: The first transformer is just persisting something to the database and then supposed to finish. Do I really need an output-channel here?

Comment: The solution was to switch to an outbound-channel-adapter. If you include this, I'll accept the answer.